# Docker bind mount directory in /tmp not working

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to mount a directory in /tmp to a directory in a container, namely /test. To do this, I've run:

`docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/tmpl42ydir5/:/test alpine:latest ls /test`

I expect to see a few files when I do this, but instead I see nothing at all.

I tried moving the folder into my home directory and running again:

`docker run --rm -it -v /home/theolodus/tmpl42ydir5/:/test alpine:latest ls /test`

at which point I see the expected output. This makes me thing I have mis-configured something and/or the permissions have bitten me. Have I missed a step in installing docker? I did it via `sudo snap install docker`, and then configured docker to let me run as non-root by adding myself to the docker group. Running as root doesn't help...

Host machine is Ubuntu 20.04, docker version is 19.03.11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When running docker as a snap...

> all files that Docker uses, such as dockerfiles, to be in `$HOME`.

Ref: https://snapcraft.io/docker

The `/tmp` filesystem simply isn't accessible to the docker engine when it's running within the snap isolation. You can [install docker directly on Ubuntu from the upstream Docker repositories](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) for a more traditional behavior.

Comment: I've had same issue on Mac using docker via Colima. Is it the same behavior like snap?

Comment: @dx7 Colima is a VM, so you are likely looking at the filesystem of the VM. There appears to be a `colima start --mount` option.

Comment: that's right. but I'm able to mount every dir but /tmp.